# How to build a project that relies on a third party COM library on a build server?

Tags: com, msbuild, build-server

I have a project that I am developing that uses a third party COM library as a reference and I would like to build this project on a Visual Studio Team Services build client.  My first idea is to create a MSBuild task that checks to see if the COM library is installed on the local computer and if it is not, go ahead and install it, but this seems like a really messy way to do this.  I have searched around but it seems as though all the answers date back years and I can't seem to make the few I have found work in a VS 2013 project.  How have other people solved this problem?  Is there a cleaner way?

For reference I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498258/tfs-build-server-and-com-references-does-this-work/8887087#8887087), which looks really clean, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go one of these routes:

- Generate interop dll with `tlbimp`, add it to your project and reference it directly:

  - In VS command prompt, execute `tlbimp.exe <your_dll>` to generate the interop dll. You can specify the name with `/out` option.
  - put this dll somewhere with your code
  - reference it by going to `Add reference > Browse` and click `Browse...` to add the dll
- Generate the tlb from COM dll , add it to the project and reference the tlb:

  - Generate the tlb (e.g. using [`OLE/COM Object viewer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4990232/1663919)) or [extract it from the dll resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23224572/1663919),
  - put this tlb somewhere with your code
  - reference it by going to `Add reference > COM` and click `Browse...` to add the tlb reference to project
  - As @HansPassant noted in comments, this solution still relies on registry, but you can register it with `regtlb`, `regtlib` or similar tool, as a prebuild step, which should be easier than installing the server (though if it is just a dll, you could use `regsvr32` to register it instead of full install). However, this is still more complex than the approach with interop dll

Comment: Can you provide some implementation details or links and say what the difference in the results are for those two methods?

Comment: The second bullet doesn't address the problem, it still relies in the registry.  First one is fine and the way you should do this.